# Drawing samples from matrix normal

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition, matrix-normal

I have to generate $n \times m$ sample ($A$) from a matrix normal distribution, given two covariance matrices:

1. $n \times n$ row covariance matrix (matrix $B$) (defines the covariance between the rows of the matrix to be generated).
2. $m \times m$ column covariance matrix (matrix $C$) (defines the covariance between the columns of the matrix to be generated).

Currently, I am taking the Cholesky decomposition such that
$C = \text{Cholesky}(B) \times Z \times \text{Cholesky}(C)$. $Z$ is normal i.i.d. ($n \times m$) matrix, I am using dot product. However, the row covariance of the matrix $C$ is turning out to be quite different from matrix $B$. Where might this be going wrong?

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format any mathematics.

Comment: Matrix $B$ is of size $n \times n$ already if $m=1$. Thus $B$ cannot encode the information for larger $m$. Similar for $C$. There seems to be information missing (perhaps some covariances are zero?).

Comment: @Christian: How do you conclude that?  The OP appears to be describing the usual parameterization of the [matrix Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution).  That article, by the way, [includes an answer to this question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution).

Comment: @whuber: I am sorry that I hadn't checked the definition of the matrix normal distribution. You are right in that the OP gave the standard definition of it. I would however submit that to call $U$ the "covariance between the rows" (and analogous for $V$ and the columns) is confusing, even though it may be suggestive from examining the proof that you kindly pointed to; "row/column covariance matrix" seems standard instead. This confusion in fact motivated my question. So I suggest the final parenthetical text in 1 and 2 to be amended.

Comment: PS: Clarification: I meant the expression in the "Proof" section of the Wikipedia article you cited, which was not the section that you pointed to. I cannot edit this anymore, sorry.